# Why do i have to log in twice in backend to log in?

Tags: joomla, authentication, backend

I have to put my *username and password* in ***twice*** for the *administrator* back-end.

- The first time I type in my user name and password, I return to the login with blank fields.
- The second time I get logged in...

Are some users experiencing the same? Weard can someone help?

There is one post with a user having the same problem, but I did not find the usefull answers:
http://forum.joomla.org/viewtopic.php?t=558305

Joomla version 2.5.9

Comment: Never had this problem before. Might be a security plugin doing this. Not sure if it is a bug but update to Joomla 2.5.16

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The login problem was related to my domain configuration and the interaction with Joomla.

I updated the **.htaccess** file like:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.domain.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

In this way, my users always get redirected to: www.domain.com
Even coming to domain.com

This give them direct access, but is *also beter for other plugin's and modules that use web-cloud services*, depending on the www.domain.com (they will not work on domain.com)
Examples: Social Login with Google/Facebook/Twitter; Map API's and other API's

I hope this will help some users! It helped me :-)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and for me the way to fix this was as follows:

I had set the "live" domain to be www.mydomainname.com (in `configuration.php` in root)

When then trying to login to the backend using the domain name mydomainname.com (without the www) I had to login twice.

The answer for me was to simply ensure that I always did login using http://www.mydomainname.com/administrator.....

If you however have specified your live domain to be without the www, then you need to use the admin login url without the www accordingly.