# Joomla back-end needs two times login? Why?

Tags: joomla, authentication, backend, administrator

My login problem is reproducable on different Joomla sites.
I have this for a Joomla version 2.5.9 and 3.2.

***Backend users need to put my username and password in twice to get logged in.***

Are some users experiencing the same? Can someone explain this?

**First login** at: http://my-domain.com/administrator/ For some reason, nobody can login here. This page get redirected to the second page:

**Second login** at: http://www.my-domain.com/administrator/ ***Login is possible here.***

*So, I need a WWW in the URL.* But some users keep going to the other page. Is this Joomla related? Hosting partner related?

On my ***other website,*** I have the ***reverse problem***.

***Login at:*** http://www.other-domain.com/administrator/ does not work.

***Login at:*** http://other-domain.com/administrator/ is the redirect page and works.

There is one post with a user having the same problem, but I did not find the usefull answers: http://forum.joomla.org/viewtopic.php?t=558305

**Thanks! Any help or explanation is useful. I realy need this explanation for my customers.**

Comment: If I remember rightly, I think this was answered a few months ago. A user was having the same issue. I believe there was a redirect in com_redirect. Have a look there ;)

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/20095349/1983389

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The login problem was related to my domain configuration and the interaction with Joomla.

I updated the **.htaccess** file like:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.domain.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

In this way, my users always get redirected to: www.domain.com
Even coming to domain.com

This give them direct access, but is *also beter for other plugin's and modules that use web-cloud services*, depending on the www.domain.com (they will not work on domain.com)
Examples: Social Login with Google/Facebook/Twitter; Map API's and other API's

I hope this will help some users! It helped me :-)

Answer (score 0):

This can be caused through a conflict between a redirect in the .htaccess settings and the $live_site parameter in the configuration.php file.

For example, the $live_site parameter in configuration.php may be set to the non-www version of the website while a redirect in the .htaccess file may  be redirecting the www version of the website or vice versa.

Either make these consistent or don't set the $live_site parameter. Setting the $live_site parameter is usually not required for a website in the root folder on properly configured hosting unless there is a particular requirement (e.g. sh404SEF or similar).